# Visual Studio find in *.cs files but not in *.aspx.cs and *.ascx.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What I want is to search in all *.cs files but not in *.aspx.cs and *.ascx.cs files. So all files found must be Something.cs, not Something.aspx.cs etc.

Couldnt find an answer for this when I searched stackoverflow. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: An answer to what? What did you try, what didn't work, what did you expect? The extension is `*.cs` in all these cases. Are you asking how to *exclude* files from the search?

Comment: A quick look at the built in default filters quickly uncovers how to exclude certain file extensions. Yes, you can combine positive and negative filters.

Comment: @JeredriqDemas *Edit the question and ask what you really want*. This would be a *good* question if you actually asked what you want - I haven't thought of excluding patterns from searches until now. I can't upvote such an obscure question though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Visual Studio Menu -> Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files

The this form will pop up:

[image]

Then you can custom on "File Types" field.

Comment: You'll have to explain how this image answers the question. What parts of the image exclude `*.ascx.cs`? It may be obvious to you but it's definitely not obvious to the poster